# id is being replaced by _id, of the inner object, when updating data of MongoDB using Java Driver

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to update an object of MongoDB. I'm using Java Driver (Sync).

After a 'create' operation, the data is persisted as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f2b7deb62798d1045a47313"),
    "name" : "John",
    "other_info" : {
        "images" : {
            "images" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "1",
                    "imgType" : "IDBACKIMAGE"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "2",
                    "imgType" : "SIGCARDIMAGE"
                }
            ]
        },
    },
    "status" : "PENDING"
}
```

Now, I want to modify the 'id' parameter of the images array. So I update the data using `getCollection().updateOne(filterCondition, combine(updateData))`, but it is persisted as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f2b7deb62798d1045a47313"),
    "name" : "John",
    "other_info" : {
        "images" : {
            "images" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "3",
                    "imgType" : "IDBACKIMAGE"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "4",
                    "imgType" : "SIGCARDIMAGE"
                }
            ]
        },
    },
    "status" : "PENDING"
}
```

As you can see in the updated data, the 'id' property of the images array is now '_id' after update operation. I had provided the JSON with 'id' field but somehow the Mongo Client considered 'id' as '_id' and persisted '_id'. This happens when `replaceOne()` is used too. This doesn't happen with the create operation as you can see above. Is this an expected behavior when update operation is done? Why is MongoDB treating 'id' and '_id' as same?

Comment: Can you please specify your filter and update parameters? MongoDB does not normally convert those fields because it thinks it should be _id.

Comment: I'm executing: updateOne({"userId":"someId"}, combine(updateList)). updateList containes two SimpleUpdate objects (one for userId and another for other_info parameter) with $set operator.

Comment: I understand, but it is not possible to help unless you show what code you exactly use.

Comment: I think I found the answer here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2750

Comment: That's nice you found the problem. Yet you never mentioned you were using your POJO class to create those documents.